# Processor frequency gets reduced and doesn't recover

Tags: intel, cpu, cpufreq

I'm using a Dell Latitude E7440 (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz) and run an up-to-date Ubuntu 16.04.

When I normally run `cpufreq-info` I get something like

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.30 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.30 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.70 GHz.
```

for each CPU core. Under heavy load the computer becomes very slow and doesn't recover even if I close all programs and kill all the processes. If I run `cpufreq-info` then I get

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.30 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.30 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 133 MHz.
```

I tried to install/uninstall the `intel-microcode` package but it doesn't make any difference.

Does anybody have a suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Could you please add the output for `grep model /proc/cpuinfo` to your question (just one of the repeating set of information is good enough). I want to be able to look at the intel_pstate.c code to determine if it uses the performance or load based code path. It is likely that you computer has overheated, rather severely, and Clock Modulation has become enabled. The intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, performance path (not to be confused with the performance governor) is incompatible with clock modulation and will always result in CPU frequencies below the minimum for the processor.

Comment: Could you check the temperature when this happens using `sensors` command. Also upload `/var/log/kern.log` to https://paste.ubuntu.com or http://pastebin.com

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like one of the two following bugs:

1. thermald incompatibility with the firmware/microcode.  Purge the thermald package, and do a full power cycle (power off+power on) on the system.
2. Regression caused when the processor microcode is *updated*.  Update the system firmware to the latest available (to get a newer microcode installed when the system is powered up), and ensure you have the latest intel-microcode package installed, i.e. ensure you have *at least* version 3.20160714.1 of the intel-microcode package.  Download and install it manually if you have to, I don't believe Ubuntu has propagated that update to all versions of their distribution yet.

References:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815990

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thermald/+bug/1480349

Comment: By "update the system firmware" I do mean install the latest UEFI/BIOS update from the system vendor/motherboard vendor...

Comment: do you have any hint on how to update the microcode? The `intel-microcode` package is older than the version you suggested and i tried to update the microcode using `iucide_tool -write-earlyfw...` but it doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: ok found it. There is an instruction here: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Intel_microcode . There is just a small mistake, this line in the updated grub file `initrd="early_ucode.cpio /$i"` should be `initrd="early_ucode.cpio /boot/$i"`. Otherwise it doesn't boot.

Comment: anonymous you can edit your post rather than commenting. @Jonas you can also suggest an edit to this post to improve it. Better to have all the useful info in the answer.

Comment: I still have the same problem... I downloaded the most recent microcode from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/ (7/14/2016) and use `iucode_tool` to update but `dmesg` says `0x1f, date = 2016-04-01`.  I tried plenty of different BIOS + microcode combinations but the problem persists. Any further suggestions?